# ¿Cómo obtener la cantidad de días de la semana en un intervalo de fechas?

Tags: r

Supongamos que tenemos dos fechas que establecen un rango de días, por ejemplo:

```
from.date <- as.Date('2018-03-01')
to.date <- as.Date('2018-03-31')
```

Lo que queremos es encontrar cuantos días `lunes`, `martes`, `miércoles`, `etc` hay en dicho intervalo, una salida similar a esta :

```
     lunes    4
    martes    4
 miércoles    4
    jueves    5
   viernes    5
    sábado    5
   domingo    4
```

Nota: Estos datos corresponde al intervalo del ejemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una función que lo hace, aunque es algo fea funciona bien:

```
cdias<-function(from,to){
  d<-c("lunes","martes","miércoles","jueves","viernes","sábado","domingo")
  to<-as.Date(to)
  from<-as.Date(from)
  dif<-to-from
  dias<-round((dif)/7)
  drest<-dif-dias*7+1
  w<-which(d==weekdays(from))
  r<-rep(dias,7)
  for(i in 1:drest){
    if(w<=7){
      r[w]<-r[w]+1
      w<-w+1
    }else{
      w<-1
      r[w]<-r[w]+1
      w<-w+1
    }
  }
  r<-as.data.frame(cbind(dias=d,n=r))
  return(r)
}

cdias("2016-01-11","2018-01-24")
```

Comment: Nada mal, en cuanto a performance sin duda la mejor. Lo único que tal vez le modificaría es la forma en que determinas los nombres de la semana por algo más dinámico como: `d<-weekdays(as.Date(4,"1970-01-01",tz="GMT")+0:6)`

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en cuanto a la determinación de los días de la semana.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma simple que no me gusta mucho pero sin duda es efectiva, es usar la "fuerza bruta" y generar todas las fechas del intervalo y aplicar la función [`weekdays()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/weekdays) a cada una:

```
fechas <-data.frame(cant=seq(from = from.date, to = to.date, by = "days"))
fechas$wday <- factor(weekdays(fechas$cant), levels=weekdays(as.Date(4,"1970-01-01",tz="GMT")+0:6),ordered = TRUE)
aggregate(cant ~ wday, fechas, length)
```

La salida:

```
       wday cant
1     lunes    4
2    martes    4
3 miércoles    4
4    jueves    5
5   viernes    5
6    sábado    5
7   domingo    4
```

Comentarios:

- Los nombres de las fechas, obviamente son internacionalizados
- Como nos interesa que la salida este ordenada desde el lunes, necesitamos convertir los días de semana a un `Factor` pero ordenados por día, pero al ser los nombres dependientes del lenguaje, generamos el orden a partir de una semana que sabemos empieza un lunes `levels=weekdays(as.Date(4,"1970-01-01",tz="GMT")+0:6)`
- Lo último es agrupar por día con `aggregate(cant ~ wday, fechas, length)` y contar las ocurrencias

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr) 

fechas <- data.frame(cant = seq( 
  from = ymd(20180301),   
  to = ymd(20180331),     
  by = "days"))

fechas %>% 
  mutate(cant = weekdays(cant)) %>% 
  count(cant)
```

¿Por qué `lubridate::`? Porque `ymd()` y otras similares parsean prácticamente cualquier cosa como fecha.

```
ymd("2017enero20") == ymd(20170120) 
ymd (170120) == ymd("2017-01-20")                         #
```